# Hidden Tippy.js by MUI Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tippyjs, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using Tippy react and MUI Datagrid.

I have an element showing a Tippy in my datagrid, but when it spawns below the bottom border of the datagrid, it's hidden behind.

It's not doing the same using standard Table, but I need a Datagrid.

How can I make my Tippy be on top of the datagrid ?

This is the column definition of the concerned cell :

```
 {
            field: "informations",
            headerName: "Informations",
            renderCell: (params) => (
                <Tippy
                    theme="light"
                    content={<ReportTippy report={params.row} />}
                >
                    <IconButton
                        disableFocusRipple
                        disableTouchRipple
                        disableRipple
                        size="small"
                        color="info"
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleQuestion} />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tippy>
            ),
        }
```

Thank's in advance !